# Is it possible to add two Refinement Web Part in a search page in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, refinement-panel, refiner

When I add two (or more) Refinement Web Part in a search page they always shows the same results also if I set different configurations on each one.. 
How I can configure them in order to show different results?
For example I would add a Refinement on the left side of the page showing only "peoples" and add **another** Refinement on the right side showing only "places". I tried but the two Refinements show the same things..

Can I configure the default Refinement panel or develop a custom one in order to work as I want?

Answer (score 2):

first you need to edit one of your refinement web parts.[Change web part query.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549985%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> Allow this Web Part and other Web Parts with the same query ID to
>   display results from the same query. Under Results Query Options, in
>   the Cross-Web Part query ID box, select User query. All other
>   selections do not give results.

You need to make your refinement panels to look in different locations.
Other way is to make your own custom refinement and add custom category.
[Custom Refinement](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2010/10/custom-refinement-filters-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: Thank you for the usefull answer. I have one question: do you know how this problem could be solved in SP2013?

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2013 there is a property **Refinement Target**:
[Configure properties of the Refinement Web Part.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg549985(v=office.15).aspx)

I've never made search in SharePoint 2013 but I think it's the same as on SharePoint 2010 query id.

> In the Web Part tool pane, in the Refinement Target section, select the Web Part from which  to filter search results. By default, the Search Results Web Part is selected.